# How to create variables in a template file in ruby?

Tags: ruby, templates

I want to have a text template file that would contain variables.

- the file is read
- variables replaced with its values
- the file is saved

---

- I tried to have a file with `#{my_variable}` but actually the character `#` is escaped so `#{my_variable}` is not replaced with the value of the variable because it's text.
- tried to escape # in the text file `\#` but it didn't work

Is there any way that I don't have to do search and replace in this scenario?

Comment: use ERB or Moustache, or unescape #'s and then eval

Comment: well, in ruby escaping # is ##, so I belive transform all ## => #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As clyfe mentioned, you should definitely be using ERB's for this:

http://www.rrn.dk/rubys-erb-templating-system/

This will let you use variables, loops, methods, etc. and is far more robust.